# Validation of Month and Year

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

I'm using a custom validation to check if a card has expired (it has a month / year).

Here's what I've got:

```
    validate :card_not_expired

    def card_not_expired
      if exp_year > Time.now.year or 
        (exp_year == Time.now.year and exp_month >= Time.now.month)
        true
      end
    end
```

I'm getting a `undefined method ">=" for nil:NilClass` message, presumably because the `exp_month` and `exp_year` fields can't be accessed directly in the Model. I tried using the symbol form (`:exp_month`) but not surprisingly, that didn't work either.

How do I get it to work?

Comment: Can you put your model please?

Comment: exp_year is not a required for this reason in some times can be nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    def card_not_expired
      if exp_year.present? and (exp_year >= Time.now.year or 
        (exp_year == Time.now.year and exp_month >= Time.now.month))
        true
      end

      # Raise error for expired card
      errors.add(:exp_month, "can't be in the past")
    end
```

Validations are executed when you create new object, and in this moment you have not value for exp_year, in order to work you must use present? or make validation only executed before save

COPY PASTE FROM [RailsValidations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#when-does-validation-happen-questionmark)

There are two kinds of Active Record objects: those that correspond to a row inside your database and those that do not. When you create a fresh object, for example using the new method, that object does not belong to the database yet. Once you call save upon that object it will be saved into the appropriate database table. Active Record uses the new_record? instance method to determine whether an object is already in the database or not. Consider the following simple Active

Comment: I already validate the presence of `exp_year`. See `validates_presence_of :exp_month, :exp_year, :cvc, :number`

Comment: You need tou use exp.year.present? because validations are running when you create a object

Comment: No error, but now it seems to skip the validation altogether.. it doesn't fail when I pass an expired card.

Comment: I think that I made a fail in use of and and or, I editred with correct use of paretensis, check too that a integer >= Time.now.year works in your rails console

Comment: I was missing the `errors.add(:expiration_date, "can't be in the past")` at the end. Works now..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this methods to check if the card has expired:

```
def card_expired?
 expiration = Time.utc(exp_year, exp_month, month_days, 23, 59, 59)
 Time.now.utc > expiration
end

def month_days
  mdays = [nil,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
  mdays[2] = 29 if Date.leap?(year)
  mdays[exp_month]
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but there's no day (it's just MM/YY). My issue was with attaching it to the validation..

Comment: @FloatingRock That's why month_days method exists, to check the number of days of every month.

Comment: It's a card with just a month and year fields. Why are we talking about days?

Comment: The card is valid until the last second of month, so you need to set the expiration date with the card year, month, last days of that month and last second, to compare with actual time.

Comment: @FloatingRock validate :card_expired?